# Thread1 exc_bad_access (code =2)... help me

Tags: ios, objective-c

i've been fixing this problem for a few days. but can't seem to get it.. 
help me out ..

let me explain my situation. Basically, i have **navigation controller** that contains **table view** controller and **view** controller. and i'm making simple phone book app.

And, i have a directory entry declared in **extension class**

```
@interface DetailViewController ()

@property DirectoryEntry *dirEntry;

@end
```

And, in table view, when you click the button it will transfer some data through **segue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    DetailViewController *detailCV = [segue destinationViewController];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"cellToDetail"]) {

        [detailCV setDirEntry: [self.pbArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView     indexPathForSelectedRow].row]];

    } else {

        detailCV.dirEntry = nil;

    }

    //designate delegate !!!
    detailCV.delegate = self;

}
```

**My Problem** occurs when it execute **detailCV.dirEntry = nil;** it will call my setter in viewController. it **says EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

```
 -(void) setDirEntry:(DirectoryEntry *) dirEntry {
    self.dirEntry  = dirEntry;
}
```

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an EXC_BAD_ACCESS so much as the OS killing your app for smashing the stack.  This method is recursing infinitely:

```
-(void) setDirEntry:(DirectoryEntry *) dirEntry {
    self.dirEntry  = dirEntry;
}
```

Your use of dot notation expands to a setter which should make this more clear.

```
-(void) setDirEntry:(DirectoryEntry *) dirEntry {
    [self setDirEntry:dirEntry];
}
```

Set the instance variable directly, or let the compiler handle it.  Properties in class extensions are automatically synthesized.